# Where do I go to hire a freelance programmer?

Tags: java, c++, plugins

I want to hire a programmer freelance to develop a small InDesign plugin, but I have no idea how to go about finding one. Most of the freelance bidding sites are garbage, but aside from finding a few companies from a google search I'm not sure where else to go. Are there any good sites for posting jobs or other good ways of finding a programmer to hire?

Comment: Have you tried here: [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I was not aware of that site. I should've mentioned in my post that I was looking for a freelancer, not really a career hire. But thanks for the link!

Comment: and wow posting a job on there is expensive. I could consider that if I was a full blown company, but I'm a design freelancer myself, just looking for a single project estimate, and $350 is a lot to pay for that.

Comment: Similar question:
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/47312/best-ways-to-recruit-developers

Comment: I updated my question to emphasize the "freelance"

Comment: what about http://www.freelancer.com/info/lookingforworkers.php

Comment: You might try guru.com as well

Comment: @nCdy i checked that out, but it didn't strike me as a good place to get a quality programmer, simply because I took a look at some of the design job postings and it's fill with people wanting a ton of work dirt cheap. I'll go back and take a look though.

Answer (score 3):

You could look at http://www.odesk.com, where you can hire a freelance developer anywhere in the world.  There are tools that help protect both you and the freelancer, and you can read the feedback from other employers about the freelancer and feedback from freelancers about the employer, which gives you insight into who you would be hiring.

Answer (score 1):

I really think that **word of mouth** is your best bet.  If you are active on any of the social networking sites, ask there.  If not then ask around to anyone that works at a technical company or in a company's tech department.

There's always someone around that will do work on the side, and you'll have an easier time getting references.

Comment: I've tried all of the programmer types that I know of as far as word of mouth goes. I'm a freelance graphic designer and don't have too many technical contacts. I suppose I could try reaching out to my linkedin contacts.